# Posting multiple values with one parameter with httpclienthandler in c#

Tags: c#, http, dictionary, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to send a form to a website with HTTP Client. The Website then returns a list with data based on my request.
The process itself is working fine but I have to do 3 requests wheras one is enough when I do it by hand in the browser.

In the browser I have multiple checkboxes to apply Filters on the data. The posted http form has the following data in it:

[image]

I was able to obtain the same data by creating a dictonary in C# which I then converted to a FormUrlEncodedContent:

```
values = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "statuses[]", "2048" },
    { "issued_from", "" },
    { "issued_till", "" },
    { "listing_from", "" },
    { "listing_till", "" },
};
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
content.Headers.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
var response = GlobalVar.client.PostAsync(URI, content).Result;
```

With this method I have to make 3 requests and merge the obtained data afterwards. This is obviously not the cleanest solution with cost of my system resources, cost of server resources and internet bandwith.

I checked the unformatted headers of the request in the browser which looked like the following:

```
Referer: https://www.example.com/en/example/?statuses[]=512&statuses[]=1024&statuses[]=2048&max_results=100&page=1
```

This led me to the conclusion that I might just add the statuses three times to the dictionary:

```
values = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "statuses[]", "512" },
    { "statuses[]", "1024" },
    { "statuses[]", "2048" },
    { "issued_from", "" },
    { "issued_till", "" },
    { "listing_from", "" },
    { "listing_till", "" }
};
```

Unfortunately, a dictionary seems to work like a database and does not accept the same key value multiple times.

Does anyone have a solution on how I can post all three statuses in one single request? Can I just use something different such as

```
List<Tuple<string,string>>()?
```

best regards and many thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably better that you send a CSV string for values than an array.  If you want an array than use following :

```
Dictionary<string, string[]> values = new Dictionary<string, string[]>{
                { "statuses", new string[] {"512","1024","2048" }},
                { "issued_from", null },
                { "issued_till", null },
                { "listing_from", null },
                { "listing_till", null }
            };
```